# Haskell type classes - difference between div and /?

Tags: haskell, read-eval-print-loop

When I query the type of `div` infix operator and the `/` operator in Ghci, I find that `div` has the signature `(div) :: Integral a => a -> a -> a` while `/` has the signature `(/) Fractional a => a -> a -> a`. While they accomplish pretty much the same thing, what is the difference between type classes `Fractional` and `Integral`?

Comment: they don't do the same thing at all - `div` is division with remainder and `/`is ... well fractional division - think `5 / 2 = 2.5` vs ``5 `div` 2 = 2`` - can you see the difference? - The difference between the classes is just that - `Integral` is for numbers you can do division with remainder with and fractional is for rational-like numbers (`a/b`)

Comment: Now I See.. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Carsten: Could you post that as an answer for better visibility? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a conceptual difference between those operations:

- `div` is division with remainder (see [euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain))
- `(/)` is fractional division - this is the *inverse* operation to `(*)`

think `5 / 2 = 2.5` vs `` 5 `div` 2 = 2 ``

The difference between the *classes* is just that

- `Integral` is for numbers you can do division with remainder with
- and `Fractional` is for rational-like numbers in the form of `a/b` - think of `1/2` or `2/7`, etc.

Indeed this is a common problem if you mix both `Fractional` and `Integral` operations like `div` and `(/)` as just within the *prelude* there is no type that is an instance of both of these classes and so you end up with an well-typed expression that you often cannot evaluate.

The usual *fix* for this is using `fromIntegral` to go convert into the common `Num` instance you are targeting.